# Bleed on a banner

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, print-production, bleed

Hi I'm wondering if someone can help me. What bleed should I add to a banner that is `5 meters x 1.3 meters`? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should add 1.3cm to be certain. If you're doing a pull-up banner then the top and bottom parts often need 7-10 cm as bleed! In general, the bigger the canvas, the bigger the bleed. And if the banner is attached to something then it's better to verify if there's templates or specifications available on the printer's website since the bleed will not be the same on all sides. In any case, you should always refer to the printer's website or call them; usually they have their requirements available online and easy to find. Ask your client if you don't know who's printing the banner.

Comment: Ask the production house.

Answer (score 3):

Converted to a comment per request:

You should really consult your printer on what they prefer. They may even have a template.

Some questions you should consider when deciding a bleed for a banner you print yourself:

- Is this going to be grommeted?
- Is the banner going to be hemmed?
- Is this banner going into a frame?
- Is this banner going into a lighted sign?
- Does this banner need pole pockets?
- Is this banner going to be double sided?

Answer (score -2):

the rule of thumb is that you as a minimum put 3mm bleed on any publication

Comment: Hi Gustav, welcome to GDSE! I disagree with your answer. Especially larger publications (like OP is asking about) regularly have larger bleed requirements. I have delivered bleeds of up to 20cm, myself. Don't let this discourage you, we *are* happy to have you here!

Comment: I agree with Bakabaka, there is much more to consider. That said, it is great to have you here :)

Comment: @Bakabaka: can you describe the reason for such large a bleed area? Is the item being wrapped around a substrate like a canvas (etc)?

Comment: @horatio Indeed, this example was a single-sided canvas print for a stand.